# Detecting total finger touch in Android

Tags: android, touch, ontouchlistener, motionevent

I have to take count for the total number of fingers clicked on screen.

Used Touch event as below :

```
relTouch.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {

            switch(event.getPointerCount()){
                case 1:
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Single touch", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    break;
                case 2:
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Double touch", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    break;
                case 3:
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Triple touch", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    break;
            }
            return true;
        }

    });
```

It's working fine.

But, The issue is When I tap with more than one finger, It also giving me single click. If I tap with 3 fingers, it also gives me Single and Double click.

How to solve this ?

Comment: Correct me If I am wrong, it is a touch listener. So it counts when there is a touch. What do you mean more than one finger ? It wont count number of fingers, right ?

Comment: getPointerCount() returns number of fingers. The current number of pointers can be obtained via a call to the getPointerCount() method of the current MotionEvent object.

Comment: The pointer index of each pointer in the event ranges from 0 to one less than the value returned by getPointerCount(). Did you read `android developer guide`. I am just trying to understand here.

Comment: This what suggested in `developer guide`. Have a look https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/MotionEvent#getPointerCount()

Comment: @cantona_7 Have you understand sir, What we need to change here...?

Comment: Anyone here to look in to issue and resolve ?